# Use writer instead of calc to run a macro

Tags: libreoffice-basic

I am trying to write an extension to install a macro. I have followed all the steps mentioned in the tutorial.

https://github.com/luane-aquino/helloworld-libreoffice-extension

It is working as expected. The only problem is that I need the icon to be available in writer and not in calc.

Comment: Please look in the **Addons.xcu** file, in the **"MergeContext"** section. Doesn't it seem suspicious to you that `com.sun.star.sheet.SpreadsheetDocument`  is listed there? *Hint: try `com.sun.star.text.TextDocument`*

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Is it possible to assign a keyboard shortcut to a macro that is being installed through an extension?

Comment: I'm not sure what will help you - [**this**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Framework/Article/Accelerators_Configuration) or [**this**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/set-keyboard-shortcuts-for-extensions/26688?u=johnsun)